# Exporting anchors across YAML files

Tags: anchor, yaml

```
--- #File A
  - Lunch: &01
        - Chicken
        - Rice
        - Sallad
...

--- #File B
  - Monday: *01
  - Tuesday: *01
...
```

For example File A is in C:drive in my PC and File B is in D:drive.

How can I export the anchors Using YAML?

Comment: This question is pretty similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76677480/20269772). I recommend having a look at it

Answer (score 19):

You can't share anchors/aliases between documents; [Chapter 9.1 of the YAML 1.2 spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2800132) explicitly states that each document is completely independent.