# How to set dynamic values with Kubernetes yaml file

Tags: templates, kubernetes, yaml, config, key-value

For example, a deployment yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: guestbook
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: guestbook
      spec:
        container:
          - name: guestbook
            image: {{Here want to read value from config file outside}}
```

There is a `ConfigMap` feature with Kubernetes, but that's also write the key/value to the yaml file. Is there a way to set the key to environment variables?

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620674/use-placeholders-in-yaml

Comment: Of all the options posted below, Kustomize is **not the easiest** tool to have variables in YAML files, but is the most *native way* to do this in kubernetes – since Kustomize is now directly usable inside kubectl. OP's exact use case would be the concept of ***Image Transformers*** but there's many other replacement options. The official documentation is VERY lacking in examples, so I always point people to this article from 2023 to learn the different Kustomize concepts: https://devopscube.com/kustomize-tutorial/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to set image through variable or Config Map in Kubernetes. But you can use for example [Helm](https://helm.sh/) to make your deployments much more flexible and configurable.

Answer (score 119):

You can also use [`envsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) when deploying.

e.g.

```
cat app/deployment.yaml | envsubst | kubectl apply ...
```

It will replace all variables in the file with their values.
We are successfully using this approach on our CI when deploying to multiple environments, also to inject the `CI_TAG` etc into the deployments.

Comment: Also possible without cat: `envsubst < deployment.yaml | kubectl apply -f -`

Comment: Do you have an example of `envsubset` and `deployment ` so we can see syntax of the variables declarations and anchros?

Comment: You just put $YOUR_ENV_NAME in the file, that's it.

Comment: I put in a quick post to supplement this.  Thanks.  Ya - online I see all sorts of syntax $FOO ${FOO} {{FOO}} etc.. so it wasn't clear.

envsubst < k8s/pls-invoice-rest-dep.yaml | kubectl apply -f -

Comment: Edit queue is full, so I added here. `cat app/deployment.yaml`, there is no $.

Comment: I agree with @NoamManos cat is so uncivilized !! :D

Answer (score 78):

You can't do it automatically, you need to use an external script to "compile" your template, or use helm as suggested by @Jakub.

You may want to use a custom bash script, maybe integrated with your CI pipeline.

Given a template yml file called `deploy.yml.template` very similar to the one you provided, you can use something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# sample value for your variables
MYVARVALUE="nginx:latest"

# read the yml template from a file and substitute the string 
# {{MYVARNAME}} with the value of the MYVARVALUE variable
template=`cat "deploy.yml.template" | sed "s/{{MYVARNAME}}/$MYVARVALUE/g"`

# apply the yml with the substituted value
echo "$template" | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer! I have read `helm` document. It's a great tool. Your script is a right way to deploy an application with CI.

Comment: This was solution for me to template Kubernetes Job manifest. Thank you!

Comment: If I need to replace 2 variables how do I do that ?

Answer (score 38):

One line:

```
cat app-deployment.yaml | sed "s/{{BITBUCKET_COMMIT}}/$BITBUCKET_COMMIT/g" | kubectl apply -f -
```

In yaml:

```
  ...
  containers:
  - name: ulisses
    image: niceuser/niceimage:{{BITBUCKET_COMMIT}}
  ...
```

Comment: or with the default value - `cat app-deployment.yaml | sed "s/{{BITBUCKET_COMMIT}}/${BITBUCKET_COMMIT:=1}/g" | kubectl apply -f -`

Comment: You all deserve the [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)! `sed` can read files perfectly fine on its own, all remaining arguments are parsed as input file paths.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @CelinHC this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is BITBUCKET_COMMIT an env variable?  Where is the value actually set so that it can be substittuded?

Comment: Hi... what if I need to replace 2 or 3 variable in the file

Comment: @yasinmohammed just add another `sed` entry in the command like `cat ...| sed ...| sed ... | kubectl apply`

Comment: I added the sed and its working the kubectl apply part am not able to get `cat filename | sed ... | sed ... | kubectl apply -f  -n logs`

Comment: I added the kubectl as a separate command after outputting to /tmp

Answer (score 12):

After trying `sed` and `envsubst` I found [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) the most elegant and Kubernetes-native way. As an alternative also [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) comes in handy sometimes.

### Use Kustomize to change image name

[Install](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/installation/kustomize/) the `kustomize` CLI (e.g. on a Mac this is `brew install kustomize`) and create a new file called `kustomization.yaml` in the same directory as your `deployment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - deployment.yaml
```

Now use the `kustomize edit set image` command to change the image name

```
# optionally define image name
IMAGE_NAME=ghcr.io/yourrepo/guestbook:c25a74c8f919a72e3f00928917dc4ab2944ab061

# replace image tag
kustomize edit set image $IMAGE_NAME
```

Finally apply your kustomized `deployment.yml` to your cluster using `kubectl apply -k directory/where/your/kustomization/file/is` like this:

```
kubectl apply -k .
```

For debugging you can see the resulting `deployment.yml` if you run `kustomize build .` :

```
$ kustomize build .
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: guestbook
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: guestbook
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: ghcr.io/yourrepo/guestbook:c25a74c8f919a72e3f00928917dc4ab2944ab061
          name: guestbook
```

### Alternative: Use yq to change image name

[Install the YAML processor yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/#install) (e.g. via homebrew `brew install yq`), define your variables and let yq do the replacement:

```
# define image name
IMAGE_NAME=ghcr.io/yourrepo/guestbook:c25a74c8f919a72e3f00928917dc4ab2944ab061

# replace image tag
yq e ".spec.template.spec.containers[0].image = \"$IMAGE_NAME\"" -i deployment.yaml
```

Now your `deployment.yaml` get's the new image version and then looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: guestbook
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: guestbook
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: ghcr.io/yourrepo/guestbook:c25a74c8f919a72e3f00928917dc4ab2944ab061
          name: guestbook
```

FYI: Your `deployment.yaml` isn't really valid Kubernetes configuration - the `template.spec.container` should not reside under the `metadata` tag - and also it is spelled `containers`.

Comment: in kustomize, there is such concept called overlays, you can set different values for different environment; and i assume `kustomize edit set <tag name>  <tag value>` does the same effect

Answer (score 11):

This kind of thing is painfully easy with [`ytt`](https://get-ytt.io):

`deployment.yml`

```yaml
#@ load("@ytt:data", "data")
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: guestbook
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: guestbook
      spec:
        container:
          - name: guestbook
            image: #@ data.values.image
```

`values.yml`

```
#@data/values
image: nginx@sha256:fe2fa7bb1ceb86c6d9c935bc25c3dd8cbd64f2e95ed5b894f93ae7ffbd1e92bb
```

Then...

```
$ ytt -f deployment.yml -f values.yml | kubectl apply -f -
```

or even better, use `ytt`'s cousin, [`kapp`](https://get-kapp.io) for a high-control deployment experience:

```
$ ytt -f deployment.yml -f values.yml | kapp deploy -a guestbook -f -
```

Comment: is `ytt` standard on linux or something we need to install ahead of deploy?

Comment: You install it: https://carvel.dev/ytt/docs/latest/install/

Comment: Why are more people not talking about this, looks really great!

Comment: @NicholasPetersen Yeah, it's unfortunate that we haven't been able to spread "the word" better about the Carvel tools like `ytt`.

Glad you see value in it. Don't be shy in sharing with others you think would benefit.

Answer (score 9):

I create a script called `kubectl_create` and use it to run the create command. It will substitute any value in the template that is referenced in an environment variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
eval "cat <<EOF
$(<$1)
EOF
" | kubectl create -f -
```

For example, if the template file has:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service

metadata:
  name: nginx-external
  labels:
    app: nginx

spec:
  loadBalancerIP: ${PUBLIC_IP}
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443

  selector:
    app: nginx
```

Run `kubectl_create nginx-service.yaml` and then the environment variable PUBLIC_IP will be substituted before running the actual kubectl create command.

Comment: why not out="$(cat $1)" and kubectl apply -f out ... maybe I am missing something

Answer (score 7):

yaml does not read values from another yaml file. As an alternative approach you could try this.

```
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  annotations:
    namespace: &namespaceId dev
    imageId: &imgageId nginx
    podName: &podName nginx-pod
    containerName: &containerName nginx-container
  name: *podName
  namespace: *namespaceId
spec:
  containers:
  - image: *imgageId
    name: *containerName
    resources: {}
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Comment: How is this any better than just hardcoding these values?  If they are in the same file...

Comment: @AdamHughes it's better because there's a single source of truth for the values with this approach. This is important because say for example you forget to replace all, or there's a typo in one value. Instead of checking them all there's just this reference. Imagine a very long connection string, it would be tedious to maintain in more than one place in the file.

Answer (score 3):

My approach:

`tools/jinja2-cli.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

sys.stdout.write(Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates/')).from_string(sys.stdin.read()).render(env=os.environ) + "\n")
```

Make rule:

```
_GENFILES = $(basename $(TEMPLATES))
GENFILES = $(_GENFILES:templates/%=%)

$(GENFILES): %: templates/%.j2 $(MKFILES) tools/jinja2-cli.py .env
        env $$(cat .env | xargs) tools/jinja2-cli.py < $< > $@ || (rm -f $@; false)
```

Inside the `.j2` template file you can use any jinja syntax construct, e.g. `{{env.GUEST}}` will be replaced by the value of `GUEST` defined in `.env`

So your `templates/deploy.yaml.j2` would look like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: guestbook
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: guestbook
      spec:
        container:
          - name: guestbook
            image: {{env.GUEST}}
```

Another approach (using just `bash` builtins and `xargs`) might be

```
env $(cat .env | xargs) cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: guestbook
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: guestbook
      spec:
        container:
          - name: guestbook
            image: ${GUEST}
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the standard - Helm should be used instead of custom scripts to solve this problem nowadays. You don't need to deploy to generate Kubernets yamls on the machine.

An example:

1. Install helm on your machine so `helm` command exists
2. https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/pauls-helm-charts/helloworld - Install button
3. `helm repo add pauls-helm-charts http://tech.paulcz.net/charts`
4. `helm pull pauls-helm-charts/helloworld --version 2.0.0`
5. `tar -zxvf helloworld-2.0.0.tgz && cd helloworld`
6. `helm template -f values.yaml --output-dir helloworld . --namespace my-namespace --name-template=my-name`

So it created these files from `values.yaml`:

```
wrote helloworld/helloworld/templates/serviceaccount.yaml
wrote helloworld/helloworld/templates/service.yaml
wrote helloworld/helloworld/templates/deployment.yaml
```

Inside `values.yaml`, you can change predefined `repository` (or 100% any value can be repeated in Kubernetes yamls as you wish):

```
image:
  repository: paulczar/spring-helloworld
```

Now if you want to deploy, make sure `kubectl` works and just apply these generated files using `kubectl apply -f serviceaccount.yaml`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [kubetpl](https://github.com/shyiko/kubetpl)

It has three different template flavors and supports ConfigMap/Secret freezing.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to change the image or a tag while your deployment is running, you could set the image of a specific container in your deployment:

```
kubectl apply -f k8s
kubectl set image deployments/worker-deployment worker=IMAGE:TAG
```

Answer (score 1):

I create a script called kubectl_apply. It loads variables from .env, replace ${CUSTOMVAR} in yml and pass it to kubectl command

```
  #!/bin/bash
  set -a
  source .env
  set +a
  eval "cat <<EOF
  $(<$1)
  EOF
  " | kubectl apply -f -
```

Answer (score 1):

I've published a command-line tool [ysed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ysed) that helps exactly with that, in case you plan to script it.

Answer (score 1):

create a file called `kubectl_advance` as below and enjoy calling it just like kubectl commands.

e.g.

```
EXPORT MY_VAL="my-v1"

kubectl_advance -c -f sample.yaml # -c option is to call create command
kubectl_advance -r -f sample2.yaml # -r option is to call replace command
```

Assuming the yaml file has the value like ${MY_VAL} to be replaced by the environment variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

helpFunction()
{
   echo "Supported option is [-f] for file"
   exit 1
}

while getopts "f:cr" opt
do
   case "$opt" in
      f ) yamlFile="$OPTARG" ;;
      c ) COMMAND_IS_CREATE="true" ;;
      r ) COMMAND_IS_REPLACE="true" ;;
      ? ) helpFunction ;; # Print helpFunction in case parameter is non-existent
   esac
done

echo 'yaml file is : '$yamlFile

YAML_CONTENT=`eval "cat <<EOF
$(<$yamlFile)
EOF
"`

echo 'Final File Content is :=>'
echo '------------------'

echo "$YAML_CONTENT"


if [[ "$COMMAND_IS_CREATE" == "true" ]]; then
  COMMAND="create"
fi

if [[ "$COMMAND_IS_REPLACE" == "true" ]]; then
  COMMAND="replace"
fi

echo "$YAML_CONTENT" | kubectl $COMMAND -f -
```

Answer (score 1):

[Per YAML's spec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18871178/20269772), there's no way to do that. but...

This is possible with yq's [explode operator](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/anchor-and-alias-operators).

*Namespace, Deployment, ClusterIP, Ingress*... Clean and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```bash
cat <<EOF | yq 'explode(.)' | kubectl apply -f -
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: &namespace example-namespace
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: example-deployment
  namespace: *namespace
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: &app-label example-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: httpecho
        image: hashicorp/http-echo:0.2.3
        args:
        - "-listen=:5678"
        - "-text=hello world 1"
        ports:
        - containerPort: &app-port 5678
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: *app-label
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: &app-cluster-ip example-service
  namespace: *namespace
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: *app-label
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: *app-port
    targetPort: *app-port
---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  namespace: *namespace
spec:
  ingressClassName: caddy
  rules:
  - host: example.kubernetes.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: *app-cluster-ip
            port:
              number: *app-port
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

In OKD (a superset of k8s) `Template` objects ([docs](https://docs.okd.io/latest/openshift_images/using-templates.html#templates-overview_using-templates)) are parametrized - see the `parameters` section below. You can put any number of objects inside `Templates` such as `Deployments`/`DeploymentConfigs`, `Services`, `Ingresses`/`Routes`, etc.

Note these parameters support not just strings but also numerical values (see the double curly braces around `REPLICA_COUNT` below) and even random number generators for auto-generating fresh application credentials at each container startup (see `GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET` below):

```yaml
kind: Template
apiVersion: template.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: my-template
objects:
  - kind: BuildConfig
    apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
    metadata:
      name: cakephp-mysql-example
      annotations:
        description: Defines how to build the application
    spec:
      source:
        type: Git
        git:
          uri: "${SOURCE_REPOSITORY_URL}" 
          ref: "${SOURCE_REPOSITORY_REF}"
        contextDir: "${CONTEXT_DIR}"
  - kind: DeploymentConfig
    apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
    metadata:
      name: frontend
    spec:
      replicas: "${{REPLICA_COUNT}}" 
parameters:
  - name: SOURCE_REPOSITORY_URL 
    displayName: Source Repository URL 
    description: The URL of the repository with your application source code 
    value: https://github.com/sclorg/cakephp-ex.git 
    required: true 
  - name: GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET
    description: A secret string used to configure the GitHub webhook
    generate: expression 
    from: "[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}" 
  - name: REPLICA_COUNT
    description: Number of replicas to run
    value: "2"
    required: true
message: "... The GitHub webhook secret is ${GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET} ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Helm is exactly meant for such things and a lot more. It handle complex set of resource deployment as a group etc.

But if we are still looking for some simple alternative then how about using ant?

If you want to modify the file as part of build process or test process then you can go with ant task as well.

Using ant you can load all environment values as property or you can simply load properties file like:

```
<property environment="env" />
<property file="build.properties" />
```

Then you can have a target which converts template files into your desired yaml file.

```
<target name="generate_from_template">

    <!-- Copy task to replaces values and create new file -->
    <copy todir="${dest.dir}" verbose="true" overwrite="true" failonerror="true">

        <!-- List of files to be processed -->
        <fileset file="${source.dir}/xyz.template.yml" />

        <!-- Mapper to transform filename. Removes '.template' from the file
            name when copying the file to output directory -->
        <mapper type="regexp" from="(.*).template(.*)" to="\1\2" />

        <!-- Filter chain that replaces the template values with actual values 
            fetched from properties file -->
        <filterchain>
            <expandproperties />
        </filterchain>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Of course you can use a `fileset` instead of `file` in case you want to change values dynamically for multiple files (nested or whatever)

Your template file `xyz.template.yml` should look like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ${XYZ_RES_NAME}-ser
  labels:
    app: ${XYZ_RES_NAME}
    version: v1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: ${env.XYZ_RES_PORT}
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: ${XYZ_RES_NAME}
    version: v1
```

`env.` property being loaded from environment variables and other from property file

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

In the jitsi project the `tpl` == `frep` command is used to substitute values, an extension to `envsubst`

https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet/issues/65

I keep on using the old shell tools like sed and friends but such code is quickly unreadable when its more than a handful of value to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

For my deployments, I typically use Helm charts. It requires me to update values.yaml files periodically.

For dynamically updating YAML files, I used 'envsubst' since it is simple and does not require sophisticated configuration.
In addition, most of the tools only work with valid Kubernetes manifests, not simple YAML files.

I created a simple script to handle the YAML modification to simplify the usage

https://github.com/alexusarov/vars_replacer

Example:

```
./vars_replacer.sh -i [input_file] -o [output_file] -p "[key=value] [key=value]"
```