# Kubernetes ValidationError invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ContainerPort.containerPort: got "string", expected "integer";

Tags: kubernetes

I have following pod manifest file.in that, I have defined some environment variables.

I want to assign an environment variable value to the container port as follow.

```
- containerPort: $(PORT_HTTP)
```

but this yaml trigger error when I try to create it:
`ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[0].ports[0].containerPort): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ContainerPort.containerPort: got "string", expected "integer"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: webapp
    name: webapp
spec:
  containers:
    - env:
    - name: PORT_HTTP
      value: 8080
    - name: PORT_HTTPS
       value: 8443
    image: nginx
    name: webapp
    ports:
    - containerPort: $(PORT_HTTP)
    resources: {}
    dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
    restartPolicy: Never
    status: {}
```

How to convert string value to integer value in yaml.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296082/how-to-set-dynamic-values-with-kubernetes-yaml-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variable substitution doesn't happen in kubernetes. To achieve this, you can use [Helm](https://helm.sh/). Or you can use shell command as follows,

```sh
( echo "cat <<EOF" ; cat pod.yaml; echo EOF ) | sh > pod-variable-resolved.yaml
```

And then use it to create pod in kubernetes.

```sh
kubectl apply -f pod-variable-resolved.yaml
```