# Dynamically set values in Kubernetes yaml configuration files

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to dynamically set values in a Kubernetes ingress definition yaml file?

For example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - api.mydomain.com
  rules:
  - host: api.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: http
```

I want to extract out the hardcoded domain `api.mydomain.com` and either use a value from an environment variable, or even better some sort of abstraction config value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set dynamic values with Kubernetes yaml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296082/how-to-set-dynamic-values-with-kubernetes-yaml-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with any templating package really, like jinja2 or Go templates. That would be done before submitting the resource to the api-server, but there's no native way to do it dynamically in Kubernetes. Ingresses don't have environment variables or a way to reference configmaps.

You might also want to check out https://kustomize.io/ or [https://helm.sh/](https://helm.sh)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, that's precisely what [kustomize](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize) was made for.

Other templating solutions include [Kapitan](https://github.com/deepmind/kapitan), [ksonnet](https://ksonnet.io/), [kubecfg](https://github.com/bitnami/kubecfg), [ytt](https://github.com/k14s/ytt), [yq](http://mikefarah.github.io/yq/), and [Helm](https://helm.sh/) (more than just templating, it's also a "package manager").