# [cloud-running-a-container]: No resources found in default namespace

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I did a small deployment in K8s using Docker image but it is not showing in deployment but only showing in pods.
Reason: It is not creating any default namespace in deployments.

Please suggest:

Following are the commands I used.

```
$ kubectl run hello-node --image=gcr.io/$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID/hello-node:1.0 --port=8080 --namespace=default
pod/hello-node created

$ kubectl get pods
NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-node   1/1     Running   0          12s

$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       hello-node                                                 1/1     Running   0          9m9s
kube-system   event-exporter-v0.2.5-599d65f456-4dnqw                     2/2     Running   0          23m
kube-system   kube-proxy-gke-hello-world-default-pool-c09f603f-3hq6      1/1     Running   0          23m

$ kubectl get deployments
**No resources found in default namespace.**

$ kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   event-exporter-v0.2.5                      1/1     1            1           170m
kube-system   fluentd-gcp-scaler                         1/1     1            1           170m
kube-system   heapster-gke                               1/1     1            1           170m
kube-system   kube-dns                                   2/2     2            2           170m
kube-system   kube-dns-autoscaler                        1/1     1            1           170m
kube-system   l7-default-backend                         1/1     1            1           170m
kube-system   metrics-server-v0.3.1                      1/1     1            1           170m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arghya Sadhu's answer is correct. In the past `kubectl run` command indeed created by default a `Deployment` instead of a `Pod`. Actually in the past you could use it with so called [generators](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/#generators) and you were able to specify exactly what kind of resource you want to create by providing `--generator` flag followed by corresponding value. Currently `--generator` flag is deprecated and has no effect.

Note that you've got quite clear message after running your `kubectl run` command:

```
$ kubectl run hello-node --image=gcr.io/$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID/hello-node:1.0 --port=8080 --namespace=default
pod/hello-node created
```

It clearly says that the `Pod` `hello-node` was created. It doesn't mention about a `Deployment` anywhere.

As an alternative to using **imperative commands** for creating either `Deployments` or `Pods` you can use **declarative approach**:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-node
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: hello-node
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-node
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-node
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello-node-container
        image: gcr.io/$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID/hello-node:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Declaration of `namespace` can be ommitted in this case as by default all resources are deployed into the `default` namespace.

After saving the file e.g. as `nginx-deployment.yaml` you just need to run:

```
kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment.yaml
```

#### Update:

Expansion of the environment variables within the yaml manifest actually doesn't work so the following line from the above deployment example cannot be used:

```
image: gcr.io/$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID/hello-node:1.0
```

The simplest workaround is a fairly simple `sed` "trick".

First we need to change a bit our project id's placeholder in our deployment definition yaml. It may look like this:

```
image: gcr.io/{{DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID}}/hello-node:1.0
```

Then when applying the deployment definition instead of simple `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml` run this one-liner:

```
sed "s/{{DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID}}/$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID/g" deployment.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

The above command tells `sed` to search through `deployment.yaml` document for `{{DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID}}` string and each time this string occurs, to substitute it with the actual value of `$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mario, quite a great detailed description.
Really helpful for a new learner like me.

Comment: Another finding 
Instead of "image: gcr.io/$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID/hello-node:1.0" variable in this line we need to have an actual project ID because kubectl is not able to convert the environment variable under yaml file to an absolute path. I just faced an error.
If you think there is an another way of executing the user profile with yaml please suggest.

Comment: Right, moving environment variable into deployment definition definitely isn't a good idea as it won't work. [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52787) you can find discussion on this topic and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296082/how-to-set-dynamic-values-with-kubernetes-yaml-file) thread you can read about possible solutions.

Comment: Additionally I updated my answer by adding the example workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Check version of kubectl using `kubectl version`

From kubectl 1.18 version `kubectl run` creates only pod and nothing else. To create a deployment use `kubectl create deployment` or use older version of kubectl