# Use "variables" in kubernetes service definition

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

the following is the service definition

```yaml
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: '60'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: 'true'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:iam::xxx:server-certificate/project-ssl-cert2xxx01
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: elb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-additional-resource-tags: 'Name=nginx-ingress-${ENVIRONMENT}-elb,owner=devops,k8s=true'
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.11.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.34.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: tohttps
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

there is this line in **.metadata.annotations** containing `${ENVIRONMENT}`:

```sh
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-additional-resource-tags: 'Name=nginx-ingress-${ENVIRONMENT}-elb,owner=devops,k8s=true'
```

So what is the best (and proper way) to pass this into **kubectl apply**?

Comment: How do you deploy this yaml? do you use any CI/CD or locally ?

Comment: For now through kubectl, later - Jenkins

Comment: Maybe this could help :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296082/how-to-set-dynamic-values-with-kubernetes-yaml-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set dynamic values with Kubernetes yaml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296082/how-to-set-dynamic-values-with-kubernetes-yaml-file)

Comment: Yes it does @DavidMaze. I have decided to use `kubectl kustomize`

Comment: @DmitrySemenov Could you please write your own answer to your question? It would be more clear for the rest of the community.

Comment: @OhHiMark - yes I will, just need to finalize my solution then I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are not directly supported on templates used by `kubectl`.

There are some tools that can help with configuration templating:

- You can use Helm to deploy your resources and make use of [Helm Values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/) to separate the configs for each environment.
- Use kustomize to change [variant configs](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize#2-create-variants-using-overlays) on your template before applying it.
- [Kapitan](https://github.com/deepmind/kapitan) can handle templating too (although it's an exaggerated solution for your problem).
- Or you can do some text-processing before applying your template (e.g., `sed 's/${ENVIRONMENT}/development/g' controller-service.yaml | kubectl apply -f -`)