# k8s: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 33: found character that cannot start any token

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

hope you are doing fine,

i got that error :error:

`error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 33: found character that cannot start any token`

while trying to deploy this cronjob on my k8s cluster, can  you please check and let me know if you have any clues about the reason of having this error ?

the file is as follows:

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: resourcecleanup
spec:
  # 10:00 UTC == 1200 CET
  schedule: '0 10 * * 1-5'
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            iam.amazonaws.com/role: arn:aws:iam::%%AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER%%:role/k8s/pod/id_ResourceCleanup
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: resourcecleanup
            image: cloudcustodian/c7n
            args:
                - run
                - -v
                - -s
                - /tmp
                - -f
                - /tmp/.cache/cloud-custodian.cache
                - /home/custodian/delete-unused-ebs-volumes-policies.yaml
            volumeMounts:
                - name: cleanup-policies
                  mountPath: /home/custodian/delete-unused-ebs-volumes-policies.yaml
                  subPath: delete-unused-ebs-volumes-policies.yaml
            env:
                - name: AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
                  value: %%AWS_REGION%%
          volumes:
                - name: cleanup-policies
                  configMap:
                   name: cleanup-policies
          restartPolicy: Never

---
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem could be from your indentation method, Try using spaces and not tabs for your indentation. Use 2 spaces for each indentation. Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks buddy. This issue has been bugging me for a while.

Comment: this was the issue for me , thanks

Answer (score 8):

change:

```
              value: %%AWS_REGION%%
```

to:

```
              value: "%%AWS_REGION%%"
```

> Strings containing any of the following characters must be quoted.
>
> :, {, }, [, ], ,, &, *, #, ?, |, -, <, >, =, !, %, @, `

Could not find in kubernetes docs, but from [ansible yaml syntax:](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas)

> In addition to ' and " there are a number of characters that are
> special (or reserved) and cannot be used as the first character of an
> unquoted scalar: [] {} > | * & ! % # ` @ ,.

Comment: i tried that already but it deals with the value as a string contains the string: "AWS_REGION" it doesn't deal with it a variable..

Comment: do you want to use environment variables in your `yaml` file ? "you said "it doesn't deal with it a variable" can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Yes, i want to use it as an env variable.. when i wrapper it with "" it was invoked as a string contains "AWS_REGION" while i wanted the AWS_REGION which is eu-central-1..(a..b..c..) and so .

Comment: in that case you may either use `helm` or you  can check out any of the work around mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296082/how-to-set-dynamic-values-with-kubernetes-yaml-file but note that, as per `yaml` grammar using `%` as a starting character is forbidden. which is the point of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody else came here googling this error, then quoting both the value and the template helped me.

In values.yaml

`schedule: "@daily"`

And in your helm template:

`schedule: "{{ .Values.cronjob.schedule }}"`

It's easier to forget the last one but since the variable's value can include `@`, `*`, etc we have to quote the variable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a [`helm lint`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_lint/) against the charts:

For example, error:

```
Error: YAML parse error on server-infra/templates/service-prod.yaml: 
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 11: 
found character that cannot start any token
```

Output of lint `helm lint myrepo/charts/server-infra/` command:

```bash
[WARNING] templates/service-prod.yaml: 
object name does not conform to Kubernetes naming requirements: 
"server-infra-service-prod-%!s(<nil>)": metadata.name:
Invalid value: "server-infra-service-prod-%!s(<nil>)": 
a DNS-1035 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-',
start with an alphabetic character, and end with an alphanumeric character 
(e.g. 'my-name',  or 'abc-123', regex used for validation is '[a-z]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?')
```

Which shows that actual value is missing (`<nil>`) and must be passed during execution of helm command or chart should be adjusted accordingly.

**Upd**:
Another helpful command for such cases might be [`helm template`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/)
It is simply compile your charts and values locally without sending to kubernetes API server and prints charts with values to the output so you can clearly see all charts and lines with unsupported characters, like a variable was missing or has wrong value. The command operates as install/update in most cases and support same options so you just need to replace `helm update` to `helm template --debug` to see what is going on with your charts and values.