# Tekton Pipelines: Enable alpha features using released pipelines yaml without the need to store (& maintain) feature-flags ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, tekton, tekton-pipelines, openshift-pipelines

We'd like to use [Tekton experimental features](https://github.com/tektoncd/experimental) such as the [Pipelines In Pipelines feature](https://github.com/tektoncd/experimental/tree/main/pipelines-in-pipelines). We already [installed the feature as described in the README](https://github.com/tektoncd/experimental/tree/main/pipelines-in-pipelines#install) via `kubectl apply` but end up in an error like this:

```
Pipeline default/buildpacks-test-pipeline can't be Run; it contains Tasks that don't exist: Couldn't retrieve Task "generic-gitlab-set-status": tasks.tekton.dev "generic-gitlab-set-status" not found
```

In [this issue](https://github.com/tektoncd/experimental/issues/785) it is stated, that we need to enable Tekton alpha features in our deployment. In the Tekton docs at [Customizing the Pipelines Controller behavior](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/install/#customizing-the-pipelines-controller-behavior) all feature flags are described - including the [Alpha Features](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/install/#alpha-features). The docs state we should change the `enable-api-fields:` field from `stable` to `alpha` if we want to use those features.

The recommended way of [installing Tekton Pipelines](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/install/#installing-tekton-pipelines-on-kubernetes) is to use `kubectl apply` leveraging a remotely served yaml file:

```
kubectl apply --filename https://storage.googleapis.com/tekton-releases/pipeline/latest/release.yaml
```

Inside we see the `ConfigMap` `feature-flags` (shortened):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: feature-flags
  namespace: tekton-pipelines
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: default
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: tekton-pipelines
data:
  ...
  # Setting this flag will determine which gated features are enabled.
  # Acceptable values are "stable" or "alpha".
  enable-api-fields: "stable"
  ...
```

**Is there a way to change the `enable-api-fields` field to `alpha` somehow on-the-fly without the need to store** (and in the long run maintain) **the official Tekton pipeline yaml file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple combination of `curl` which downloads the file and pipes it into `sed`, which substitutes the `stable` to `alpha` works like a charm - especially since this flag is the only line including `stable` (except of the commentary line directly above). `sed` is a common tool to [set dynamic values with Kubernetes yaml file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70152914/4964553).

You may test-drive it adding a `grep` at the end to see the lines changed with:

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/tekton-releases/pipeline/latest/release.yaml | sed "s#stable#alpha#g" | grep enable-api-fields
```

Now combining the command with a final `kubectl apply -f -` (instead of `grep`) will do what was asked for:

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/tekton-releases/pipeline/latest/release.yaml | sed "s#stable#alpha#g" | kubectl apply -f -
```

Now the officially released Tekton pipelines yaml is configured to use alpha features on-the-fly - without the need to store and maintain the `ConfigMap` in a custom git repository for example.