# How to dynamically set values containing URLs (with slashes) in Kubernetes yaml files & prevent: bad flag in substitute command

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, kubernetes, yaml, config

We're using Tekton as our CI/CD solution and want to replace the value of `{{DASHBOARD_HOST}}` inside our `pipeline-run.yml`, which looks like this:

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  generateName: buildpacks-test-pipeline-run-
spec:
  serviceAccountName: buildpacks-service-account-gitlab # Only needed if you set up authorization
  pipelineRef:
    name: buildpacks-test-pipeline
  workspaces:
    - name: source-workspace
      subPath: source
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: buildpacks-source-pvc
    - name: cache-workspace
      subPath: cache
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: buildpacks-source-pvc
    - name: maven-repo-cache
      subPath: maven-repo-cache
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: buildpacks-source-pvc
  params:
    - name: IMAGE
      value: registry.gitlab.com/jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot # This defines the name of output image
    - name: REPO_PATH_ONLY
      value: jonashackt/microservice-api-spring-boot
    - name: SOURCE_REVISION
      value: 3c4131f8566ef157244881bacc474543ef96755d
    - name: DASHBOARD_PORT
      value: 8765
    - name: DASHBOARD_HOST
      value: {{DASHBOARD_HOST}}
```

We tried to use the approach with `sed` described [in this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48297258/4964553):

```
DASHBOARD_HOST=http://abd1c6f-123246.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com
sed "s/{{DASHBOARD_HOST}}/$DASHBOARD_HOST/g" pipeline-run.yml | kubectl apply -f -
```

but get the following error:

```
bad flag in substitute command: '/'
```

Any idea on how to use `sed` to substitute the `{{DASHBOARD_HOST}}` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable you want to replace contains slashes - and `sed "s/{{DASHBOARD_HOST}}/$DASHBOARD_HOST/g"` tells `sed` to use `/` as the delimiter. This produces the error.  But [as sed `s` command can use any character as a delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16790877/4964553), we could optimize the solution using `s#` instead of `s/` like this:

```
sed "s#{{DASHBOARD_HOST}}#$DASHBOARD_HOST#g" app-deployment.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

We can also ommit the `cat` as stated by [gertvdijk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296082/how-to-set-dynamic-values-with-kubernetes-yaml-file#comment99057121_54168613) since `sed` is able to read files on it's own. The variable we want to replace inside the `app-deployment.yaml` could look somehow like this:

```
...
params:
  - name: DASHBOARD_HOST
    value: {{DASHBOARD_HOST}}
...
```

### Multiple variable substitution

Using sed you can [even replace multiple variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiple-commands-syntax.html) in your yaml file. Let's assume your `app-deployment.yaml` has the following contents:

```
...
params:
  - name: DASHBOARD_HOST
    value: {{DASHBOARD_HOST}}
  - name: DASHBOARD_PORT
    value: {{DASHBOARD_PORT}}
...
```

Now set both variables inside your shell:

```
DASHBOARD_HOST=http://abd1c6f-123246.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com
DASHBOARD_PORT=9785
```

And then [chain the sed `s#` commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiple-commands-syntax.html) using `;` like this:

```
sed "s#{{DASHBOARD_HOST}}#$DASHBOARD_HOST#g;s#{{DASHBOARD_PORT}}#$DASHBOARD_PORT#g" app-deployment.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: Hello @jonashackt. Have you solved your issue? Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: Hey @IvanM. I have solved it, yes - but I can only accept in 2 days from now on.