# Grafana CRD deployemnt secret

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, rancher

I am following the github link for the grafana operator CRD https://github.com/grafana-operator/grafana-operator/blob/v4.10.0/deploy/examples/ha/grafana.yaml

here in the database field i need to pass the password as a secret, I have tried to pass the secret in the deployment as ${secret-name} but the thing is here that when the pods get deployed the config file of grafana --> /etc/grafana/grafana.ini is showing the password as ${secret-name} instead of the actaul value.

I need that password should go via secret, not need to visible in the Grafana cdr as it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set dynamic values with Kubernetes yaml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296082/how-to-set-dynamic-values-with-kubernetes-yaml-file)